# How to highligth faces in object mode with python

Tags: python, opengl

I want to highlight certain faces via script while in object mode (I am running a modal operator to get the face index of the face under the cursor via raycast, now i want to highlight it).

Are there other ways than using bgl?
If not, does someone know a good tutorial to bring me on course with this task (never done something with OpenGL before)?

Comment: Could add a highlight material to all mesh objects, assign  highlight material to the face raycast hits `best_obj.data.polygons[face_index] = highlight_material_index`.  Would need to keep some reference to prior material index for face to reset, and remove material to clean up.

Comment: Oh, that idea is nice, will try it and report back.

Comment: I tried it with raycast modal operator template,  using  face index when "best obj" is set.  A hassle is it  needs to be  in material view mode.

Comment: @batFINGER I have it, thx :). That it does only work in material view mode is no problem: One can set the material viewport color of the highlight material to get a result in solid view mode and texture view mode, too (i will later learn a bit OpenGL to make a bgl solution but for further development this is at least adequate). If you like, post your comment as answer, so that i can confirm it.